# how do i make 384 volts at 200 amps or 80kw from a lower voltage battery source with a transformer

Tags: electric-vehicle

this is to completely replace my 2012 Nissan leaf traction battery. with a transformer.
methods I've considered.
-dc to dc boost converter
-power inverter
-voltage multiplier
-some type of unknown custom transformer
-multiple transformers
-advanced joule thief

please note: I'm no electronics expert or electrical engineer (I wish I was) but I do understand basic schematics, and this would have to be something to build at home. and please FTLOG no alien writing aka math that only professor hawking and albert Einstein only understands. and please dont not say "its not possible" or give lectures about laws of thermodynamics or what not, because thats just the lazy way of giving up. because there is a way.
here's a link of some useful information on the leaf's battery pack https://qnovo.com/inside-the-battery-of-a-nissan-leaf/

Comment: It really is not possible though. You'd need to pull almost 7 kA out of the battery--assuming 100% efficiency!--and I've never seen a car battery that can provide more than 1 kA, and that's in a short pulse.

Comment: Why do you want to change the battery \$H(s) = \dfrac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2\zeta\omega_n + \omega_n^2}\$... oops that just slipped out.

Comment: How do you know there is a way, and since you know there is a way, how can this information be obtained?

Comment: instead of a 12 volt car battery i could use a few of the original lithium ion pack cells

Comment: @jwr That's maybe more possible but a) dangerous (no, really, don't even try to) and b) why not just use *all* the original cells, with the original charge controller and everything? that way you don't have to do anything to your battery that could make it explode or something, and you don't have to try to pull absurd amounts of power out of a lead-acid battery.

Comment: Can you fit in 128 batteries so that you can have 32 in series by 4 in parallel?

Comment: I've seen a Lead acid battery that can do 80kW.  If you took the batteries out, you could fit several cars in that room.  Part of the way they got 80kW without conductors two inches thick was by using a very dangerous 600V though.  You wouldn't want to drop a wrench in there!

Comment: I took 36 12V batteries out of a UPS - no one else wanted to go near just over 400V DC - they told me it was scary :)

Comment: @SolarMike the room I walked through was a UPS for a telecommunications datacenter and they used giant batteries you lift with a little forklift.  It only had to provide power for maximum 5 minutes before the genset kicked in and it was huge.  I was happy we weren't doing work on it.  I was doing flash suit work that day so I got a bit of scare in though.  I was about 4 feet away working on some conduit another time when a coworker dropped a screw through an air vent in a UPS.  Both of us just about had a heart attack but miraculously there was no short.

Comment: Electric cars have been made with Lead-Acid batteries, you need a lot of batteries, and the performance is mediocre. Lithium-Ion energy density (by weight) is 2-5 more dense. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density

Comment: Potatoes. Copper. Zinc. 'nuff said.

Comment: @JohnCanon Thank you for causing me to learn that potato batteries outperform lemon batteries. Clearly the right choice for a producemobile.

Comment: First off, this question is off topic. Second: You can't just change battery chemistries, the controller won't know when to start/stop charging/discharging. Have you ever heard of battery energy density? Even if you did successfully run the car off of lead acid, it probably wouldn't move and the suspension would probably break because of the weight.

Answer (score 5):

Incidentally, this is the major downside of electric cars.  They use a silly amount of lithium-ion battery each, so it's a good thing a relatively small portion of the population can afford one.  Lead-acid batteries absolutely cannot compare to lithium-ion batteries on any metric other than simplicity.  This means now that your car has been designed to utilize the performance of a highly engineered lithium-ion battery, nothing short of that will do for a replacement.  Understand that making a *safe, efficient, reliable, reasonably fast charging* lithium-ion battery pack of that size is an engineering *marvel* made possible by *teams* of engineers *and other scientists and professionals*, state of the art equipment and software tools and by DIY standards, an infinite budget.  That is how *dangerous* and *complicated* lithium-ion batteries are.

If you want to *prove* to yourself that a lead-acid battery can't support 80kW, the math is actually rather easy.  You just have to look up the internal resistance of the battery (or measure it if you prefer).  The maximum power point of a source (the state in which the most power can be drawn from it) is when the source resistance equals the load resistance.  I'll do this for you.

Quick google search indicates 12V lead-acid car batteries have internal resistance of 0.02 Ohms.  Well that doesn't sound like much!  If we match it with a load of another 0.02 Ohms, we can use \$I=E/R\$ (Current equals Voltage divided by Resistance) to find the current.  12V / 0.04\$\Omega\$ = 300A.  \$P=EI\$ (Power equals Voltage times Current) so 12V * 300A = 3600W maximum from one lead-acid car battery.  This would indicate 23 car batteries would do the trick.  It's worth noting that if you run a lead-acid battery this hard it will die *fast*, probably within minutes.  So you need probably 80 or 100 batteries to get a bit of drive time, and you said you don't want to pull a trailer.  That's how *good* lithium ion batteries are.  If your car has any regenerative features and it charges your huge lead acid battery bank too fast, the batteries will also produce dangerous gasses.

To back this up, here's an helpful graph produced by NASA:

[image: Battery types energy per mass vs energy per volume]

As you can see from the graph, to store the same amount of power, disregarding other characteristics, A Lead acid battery has to be roughly six times as heavy and roughly seven times as large.

Similarly there exists *Power density*, another category in which Lithium Ion blows lead acid away.  According to Wikipedia with lead acid you get about 180 W/kg determining your maximum power output.

Looking at a randomly selected modern NAPA legend premium 8435 battery, it lists 785 cranking amps, which means the battery must maintain at least 7.2V for 30 seconds at 785A.  This amounts to a delivery of 5652 Watts, or 351 W/kg at a load much higher than could be sustained.  This would appear to bear out the number from Wikipedia.

Wikipedia lists 250-340 W/kg for Lithium-Ion but also mentions 1500 W/kg further down the page and says "Failed Verification", so I think we'd benefit from another example.

The Samsung 20S 18650 cell is rated for 30A *continuous* at a cutoff voltage (minimum) of 2.5V.  It weighs 48g, which gives it a *pessimistic* max power output of 1562 W/kg.  Building a safe, car sized cell, you'll add a bunch of weight in explosion/fire proof casings and protection circuits, but you'll still land far above the performance of a lead-acid.

It's worth noting that when you build a lithium-ion battery for high current, you limit the energy density to some degree, so there is still benefit to having a larger bank of cells with a lower draw on each, similar to lead-acid.

The other thing that's stopping you assuming your batteries can provide adequate power is that you need a charge and discharge circuit designed for your battery bank.  This isn't just bad news for your lead acid plans, it also means even with lithium-ion batteries you need a battery bank that is specifically designed to work with that car.  There is no DIY alternative and the degree of difficulty is so high you would be at *nearly infinite* probability of *spectacular, deadly* failure.  Your liability in most countries would also be huge.  Watch a few videos of comparably *tiny* "Hoverboard" batteries exploding for an idea of how fast and nasty the resultant fire/explosion is.

The only solutions I see are to find someone who can do certified maintenance on the car, or park it until you can afford to fix it properly.  I know this isn't what you wanted to hear, but hopefully it makes clear that your solution is impossible without using any language or math you won't be able to relate to.

Comment: Don't see why this was downvoted unless it was not what the OP wanted to hear. Good answer.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm open to criticism on it, especially since "80 to 100" batteries is based on peak output, but I lack the skills to home in on a better number.  23 is certainly far too few though.

Comment: Good analysis except that last graphic really doesn't say anything about the power density.

Comment: @tobalt Yeah I've found some numbers to compare, 180 W/kg for lead acid and 250 to 340 W/kg for lithium ion with an additional mention of 1500W/kg down the page with a broken reference on Wikipedia, so I'm looking into whether the 1500W/kg is just reference to high drain cells.

Comment: You can get ~108W@30A from a single high drain 18650 @ 48 grams.  That works out to 2250W/kg, one website says the battery stays cool past its 30A rating up to 40A, which would be 3000W/kg.  That would seem to indicate the lead acid needs to be between 1.5 and 16 times larger for the same power draw, but I'd like to find a graph.